# compare a pandas dataframe row against the previous days row at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, time, compare

Im trying to take a row in a dataframe and compare it to the previous days row at the same time.... and do this for all the rows
My data is in 10 minute increments and isn't even spaced so i cant use shift ( as far as i know).

so what i want to achieve is to  compare every rows timestamp against yesterdays same timestamp (for all rows).
if any one can help it would be appreciated,

expected output:

Thanks

here is the data

```
return
|t                         | min     |max      |mean    |      
---------------------------|---------|---------|------- |             
|2020-11-03 00:00:00+00:00 |0.000000 |0.851977 |0.765782|
|2020-11-03 00:10:00+00:00 |0.849415 |0.851063 |0.850166|
|2020-11-03 00:20:00+00:00 |0.849314 |0.851644 |0.850542|
|2020-11-03 00:30:00+00:00 |0.850788 |0.853111 |0.851779|
|2020-11-03 00:40:00+00:00 |0.852151 |0.855109 |0.852968|                
|2020-11-04 00:00:00+00:00 |0.000000 |0.851977 |0.765782|
|2020-11-04 00:10:00+00:00 |0.849415 |0.851063 |0.850166|
|2020-11-04 00:40:00+00:00 |0.849314 |0.851644 |0.850542|
|2020-11-04 00:50:00+00:00 |0.850788 |0.853111 |0.851779|
|2020-11-04 00:60:00+00:00 |0.852151 |0.855109 |0.852968|
```

> and here is the expected output

```
|t                         | min     |max      |mean    | match|      
|--------------------------|---------|---------|------- |------|      
|2020-11-03 00:00:00+00:00 |0.000000 |0.851977 |0.765782|0     |
|2020-11-03 00:10:00+00:00 |0.849415 |0.851063 |0.850166|0     |
|2020-11-03 00:20:00+00:00 |0.849314 |0.851644 |0.850542|0     |
|2020-11-03 00:30:00+00:00 |0.850788 |0.853111 |0.851779|0     |
|2020-11-03 00:40:00+00:00 |0.852151 |0.855109 |0.852968|0     |                
|2020-11-04 00:00:00+00:00 |0.000000 |0.851977 |0.765782|1     |
|2020-11-04 00:10:00+00:00 |0.849000 |0.851000 |0.850166|0     |
|2020-11-04 00:40:00+00:00 |0.849314 |0.851644 |0.850542|0     |                            
|2020-11-04 00:55:00+00:00 |0.852151 |0.855109 |0.852968|0     |
```

Comment: If you group by year, month, hour, and minutes, you could shift within that grouping

Comment: please provide sufficient data for an example (there is only one day here) and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper column and then join the dataframe to itself using that column. So we'll...

1. create a new column which is the previous day value we're hoping to compare:

```py
df['t_prev'] = df['t'] - pd.to_timedelta(1, 'd')
```

2. merge df to itself using `t` and `t_prev`

```py
merged_df = df.merge(df, left_on='t_prev', right_on='t', suffixes=["_left", "_right"])
```

Now you can perform whatever comparisons you need to.